# dynamically change textbox with data from MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

**My Javascript function**

```
function loadXMLDoc(para,div,ceep)
{  coode="q="+ceep;
$("#"+div).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif"> Loading...');
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: JSon.php,
        data: coode,
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg.city);
            $("#"+div).html(msg);
        }
    });

}
```

**My JSon.php file has**

```
{"id":"1","userid":"2","name":"home","address":"Room 440 Akdeniz","city":"Famagusta"}
```

**How to I retrieve the contents JSon data for dynamic setting of textbox values??**

Comment: Normally you'd do exactly what the first line of your success callback does. jQuery automatically parses the JSON for you so the parameter to the success callback is an object and you can access its properties the way your `alert(msg.city)` does. Does that not display "Famagusta"? Are you trying to ask how to assign values from different properties to different textboxes, or...?

Comment: problably insetead of  `$("#"+div).html(msg);` you would like to use the id of your textbox in order to update that and not a div in your html.